# Convert 0s to NAs when that is the only value in a row. Keep all other 0s using R

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe 'animals':

```
       ID A B C D
1    Bear 1 1 1 0
2   Tiger 0 0 0 0
3   Horse 1 0 1 0
4  Badger 0 0 0 1
5  Rabbit 1 1 0 1
6   Otter 0 0 0 0
7 Peacock 1 0 0 0
```

I would like to convert the zeros in rows only containing zeros to NAs but to leave other zeros as they are. I can do this as follows:

```
    animals$Result = rowSums(animals[2:ncol(animals)])

    df = data.frame()

    for(row in 1:nrow(animals)) {
      row = as.data.frame(animals[row,])
      if(row$Result == 0){
        row[2:5] = NA
      }
      df = rbind(df,row)
      print(row)}

df$Result = NULL
```

To obtain this:

```
ID      A  B  C  D
Bear    1  1  1  0
Tiger   NA NA NA NA
Horse   1  0  1  0
Badger  0  0  0  1
Rabbit  1  1  0  1
Otter   NA NA NA NA
Peacock 1  0  0  0
```

However, I feel there should be an easier way to do this. Is there? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We can do this without a loop by creating a logical vector based on counting the number of 0's per each row with `rowSums`.  Based on that subset the dataset without the first column and assign the rows that satisfy the condition to NA

```
df1[!rowSums(df1[-1]!=0), -1] <- NA
df1
#       ID  A  B  C  D
#1    Bear  1  1  1  0
#2   Tiger NA NA NA NA
#3   Horse  1  0  1  0
#4  Badger  0  0  0  1
#5  Rabbit  1  1  0  1
#6   Otter NA NA NA NA
#7 Peacock  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is second base R method that uses `Reduce` to find the rows to set to NA and then `lapply` to loop through the variables, with `replace` doing the replacement work.

```
# find rows to set to NA
nas <- !Reduce("|", df[-1])
# run through relevant variables, setting desired elements to NA
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], replace, nas, NA)
```

This returns

```
df
       ID  A  B  C  D
1    Bear  1  1  1  0
2   Tiger NA NA NA NA
3   Horse  1  0  1  0
4  Badger  0  0  0  1
5  Rabbit  1  1  0  1
6   Otter NA NA NA NA
7 Peacock  1  0  0  0
```